# How can i give fixed size for each columns in my gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid view and each column have different length of data.
i want to customize each columns according to data.

i have added property ControlStyle-Width="400"

but i didnt see any change when i do a debug run.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `ItemStyle-Width` attribute on the column elements

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="123" ... />
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="123" ... />
// etc.
```