# GridView automatically re-sizing itself

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView in asp that keeps re-sizing itself. Can i in some way fix the size of the GridView so it doesn't do that ? The GridView keeps shrinking itself although the data in it has the same length or is smaller

my asp code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="18" OnPageIndexChanging="Grid_PageIndexChanging"
            ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" Width="991px" Height="600px" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderWidth="1px" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" style="margin-left: 9px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequestID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <a target = "_blank" href="www.danx/default?request=<%# Eval("request")%>"><%# Eval("request")%></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Barcode">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <a target = "_blank" href="www.danx/default?barcode=<%# Eval("barcode")%>"><%# Eval("barcode")%></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="adrid" HeaderText="AdrID" SortExpression="AdrID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Navn" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="street" HeaderText="Vej" SortExpression="Street" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="houseno" HeaderText="Husnr" 
                    SortExpression="HouseNo" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="postal" HeaderText="Postnr" 
                    SortExpression="Postal" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="By" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="country" HeaderText="Land" 
                    SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lokation">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <a target = "_blank" href="https://maps.google.dk/maps?q=<%# Eval("latitude")%>,<%# Eval("longitude")%>"><%# Eval("latitudetxt")%></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="ReceivedDate" 
                    SortExpression="ReceivedDate" />

            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />

<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></RowStyle>

            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Blue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="DarkGray" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: try 
[How can i give fixed size for each columns in my gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088117/how-can-i-give-fixed-size-for-each-columns-in-my-gridview) 
or 
[How to make a GridView with maxmimum size set to the containing DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067721/how-to-make-a-gridview-with-maxmimum-size-set-to-the-containing-div)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a fixed width (991px) for the gridview, the columns would shrink/adjust as their content grow larger. One thing you could do is give fixed width to those columns you don't want resized (in % or fixed). e.g.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<a target = "_blank" href="www.danx/default?request=<%# Eval("request")%>"><%# Eval("request")%></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can also increase the size of the GridView to easily accomodate the columns e.g. Setting it to `100%` if the container is greater 991px

Answer (score 0):

is this maybe to do with the data in the cells being too long without spaces.. you can always use

```
td{word-wrap:break-word;}
```

or make sure you have spaces.

or even use styles for the columns, which set the widths explicitly

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequestID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="setWidthClass">
                <ItemTemplate>...
```

or even

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequestID" ItemStyle-Width="100">
```

of course it may be nothing to do with this.

Comment: where do i use the `td{word-wrap:break-word;}` ??

Comment: in your stylesheet, or in <style type="text/css"> ...</style> in the head of your page

Comment: i get an error stating that word-wrap is not a known CSS property name

Comment: it is css3 which is supported in most modern browsers but take a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp